# Laravel multi profile types

Tags: php, laravel

I have two members type it's player and venue how i can better create tables? Maybe players with `user_id` or merge `users` table and `players`? but what about then `venues` table?

Comment: does user has only one type ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI yes, player or venue only

Comment: You can use enum column type with predefined values ('player', 'venue'); inside your user table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create new migration, using the `migrate:make` command on the Artisan CLI. Use a specific name to avoid clashing with existing models

```
php artisan make:migration add_type_to_users_table --table=users
```

You then need to use the Schema::table() method (as you're accessing an existing table, not creating a new one). And you can add a column like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->enum('type', ['player', 'venue'])->after('email');
    });
}
```

and don't forget to add the rollback option:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('type');
    });
}
```

Then you can run your migrations:

```
php artisan migrate
```